# Initially hiding a div for later display

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, visibility

My web page is like the following:

```
<div id="id1" class="stuff">
TEXT, FORMS, and STUFF
</div>

<div id="id2" class="stuff" style="display:none">
TEXT, FORMS, and STUFF
</div>

<div id="id3" class="stuff" style="display:none">
TEXT, FORMS, and STUFF
</div>

<a id="btn1">DD</a>
<a id="btn2">DD</a>
<a id="btn3">DD</a>
```

Under this I have jQuery click events which set the display of the clicked item to inherit and the others to none.

```
$("#btn2").click(function (e) {
    $("#id1").css('display','none');
    $("#id3").css('display','none');
    $("#id2").css('display','inherit');
});
```

The showing and hiding works correctly however I do notice that some things in the initially hidden divs do not render correctly, especially the elements that get manipulated by CSS.  Essentially when the page loads the hidden divs do not correctly get rendered and when they are shown things look ugly.  What is the way to properly do this?

EDIT::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

What I ended up doing is setting all of the initially hidden divs to "visibility: none", then in the pages onLoad() event setting the display: none.  When I toggle I change both the visibility and display.  Everything renders correctly and because things are statically set to not visible there is no ugly 2 seconds where all the divs show.

Comment: How do you click on something that is not shown?

Comment: I think you have to be a little more specific, "ugly" does'nt really tell us what the problem is, and normally this should work just fine, but just doing `$("#id1, #id3").hide();` seems simpler ? I'm guessing you have a function for each element, and that the example was just poorly written with the click event on a hidden element, otherwise I tend to agree with the above comment, how does one click on a hidden element ?

Comment: Sorry.  I typed it wrong.  There are three buttons.  Elements inside the hidden divs are not rendered correctly.  When I inially unhide all the divs everything renders right.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using `visibility` instead. Example:

```
$("#id2").click(function (e) {
    $("#id1").css('visibility','hidden');
    $("#id3").css('visibility','hidden');
    $("#id2").css('visibility','visible');
});
```

Both `display` and `visibility` can have an effect on browser behavior.

An alternative work-around to both is to set the `opacity` of the divs you want to hide to `0`. That always works in my experience but is less elegant.

---

**Update in reply to comment:** In that case, you can set other properties like the `width` and `height` to `0px` and the `over-flow` to `hidden` so that the divs don't occupy any space on screen. Ugly, but basic, and works.

```
<style>
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
</style>

<div class="hidden"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/Aster_Tataricus.JPG/245px-Aster_Tataricus.JPG"/></div>
<div class="hidden"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Chamomile%40original_size.jpg/280px-Chamomile%40original_size.jpg"/></div>
<div><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Jonquil_flowers06.jpg/320px-Jonquil_flowers06.jpg"/></div>
```

You can use the jQuery `addClass` and `removeClass` methods to make the divs visible and invisible, e.g.: `$("#id1").removeClass("hidden");` and `$("#id3").addClass("hidden");`.

Comment: I can't use visibility since the div is technically still there.  The space that id1, and id2 take still offset id3 even if it's invisible.  With visibility the rendering problem is solved.  Display: none avoids this but has the rendering problem.

Comment: @user974896 - in that case, set the `width`, `height` and `over-flow` properties as well, like in the example above.

Answer (score 6):

Why not use jQuery `show` and `hide`?

Hide the elements you want to hide (duh) on page load with CSS:

```
#id1, #id2, .. {
    display: none;
}
```

Or you can hide it with Javacript:

```
$('#id1, #id2, ..').hide();
```

Show or hide them by using:

```
$('#btn2').click(function() {
    $('#id1, #id3').hide();
    $('#id2').show();
});
```

Comment: Toggling isn't the issue.  It's initially hiding the divs and having everything render correctly once they are shown.

Comment: The hide and show is nothing more then functions that set CSS properties on elements. It does the job with a few lines.

Comment: I understand but that still doesn't solve the original issue.  How would I initially hide the divs?  Remember 2 of them are hidden off the bat.

Answer (score 5):

Its best not to add display logic into your mark up a better way to do this would be

```
.hidden{ display:none;}
```

.

```
<div id="id1" class="stuff">
TEXT, FORMS, and STUFF
</div>

<div id="id2" class="stuff hidden" >
TEXT, FORMS, and STUFF
</div>

<div id="id3" class="stuff hidden">
TEXT, FORMS, and STUFF
</div>
```

.

```
$(".stuff").click(function () {
    $(".stuff").addClass('hidden');
    $(this).removeClass('hidden');

});
```

Hope that helps if your still having rendering issues then maby try

```
.hidden{ visibility:hidden; }
.stuff{display:block;}
```

Comment: Why is it better, and what exactly makes this different from the OP's code. Other than using classes to alter the CSS, it's still exactly the same ?

Comment: See addition to do with rendering also its allways best practice not to mix stlying with mark up.

Comment: Everything is in CSS.  I am typing it here as an example as I do not want to dump my site on here.  What I placed here is essentially what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I like to do it like this:
javascript:

```
$('#btn2').click(function(){
    $('#id1').addClass('hidden');
    $('#id3').addClass('hidden');
    $('#id2').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

css:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="id1" class="stuff">
TEXT, FORMS, and STUFF
</div>

<div id="id2" class="stuff hidden">
TEXT, FORMS, and STUFF
</div>

<div id="id3" class="stuff hidden">
TEXT, FORMS, and STUFF
</div>

<a id="btn1">DD</a>
<a id="btn2">DD</a>
<a id="btn3">DD</a>
```

Comment: Items inside the class="hidden" divs that were statically hidden (set class="hidden") do not load all their elements correctly when toggled.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe .toggle can help you achieve this?

```
$("#btn2").click(function (e) { 
    $("#id1").toggle(); 
    $("#id2").toggle();
    $("#id3").toggle();
});
```

Comment: The toggling works but how would I initially hide the divs so that they get loaded correctly.

Comment: @user974896 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#id1").hide();  
    $("#id2").hide(); 
    $("#id3").hide(); 
});

Comment: Wouldn't all the divs briefly show for a few seconds prior to the JS on the bottom of the page loading?  I had in my onLoad event for body the same sort of logic (although I was toggling display=none).  All the divs showed for a second or two.  My solution in the edit (starting with visibility none) solved that.

Comment: @user974896 Could use the z-index css styling instead - set it to be behind the page then with the click function that toggles add in a command to change the css z-index to a visible state before the toggle commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = pre_loader;

function pre_loader() {

    javascript:document.getElementById('loader').style.visibility='hidden';

    javascript:document.getElementById('loader').style.opacity=0;

}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to how this answer is superior to the answer in the OP